# SQL Server 2000 - Remote Connection ODBC

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I have four machines:

- XP with SQL 2000 (Machine A, the one I'm having problem with)

  - firewall:off
  - port:1433
- XP with SQL 2000 (Machine B)

  - firewall:off
  - port:1433
- XP (Machine C)
- XP (Machine D)

Note:

- All machines are in one workgroup
- All have dynamic IP addresses

**Tests Done:**

Machine A:

- ping Machine B - **OK**
- ping Machine C - **OK**
- ping Machine D - **OK**
- telnet B on port 1433, error
- connect to local SQL - **OK**
- connect to Machine B's SQL - **ERROR**

Machine B:

- ping Machine A - **OK**
- ping Machine C - **OK**
- ping Machine D - **OK**
- telnet A on port 1433, error
- connect to local SQL - **OK**
- connect to Machine A's SQL - **ERROR**

Machine C:

- ping Machine A - **OK**
- ping Machine B - **OK**
- ping Machine D - **OK**
- telnet A on port 1433, error
- telnet B on port 1433, error
- connect to Machine A's SQL - **ERROR**
- connect to Machine B's SQL - **OK**

Machine D:

- ping Machine A - **OK**
- ping Machine B - **OK**
- ping Machine C - **OK**
- telnet A on port 1433, error
- telnet B on port 1433, error
- connect to Machine A's SQL - **ERROR**
- connect to Machine B's SQL - **OK**

[image: Error Print Screen]

I can't connect to Machine A's SQL Server. A and B have the same configurations, they have no network problems, but why A is not working? How to troubleshoot this? Please I've read enough articles from Microsoft. Anybody encountered the same problem before? Is there any chance that a pc can be pinged but has a problem in physical network?

Comment: What port is SQL listening on for machine A? Can you telnet to that from the other machines?

Comment: @Colin, i got error when try telnet on both servers, that's weird coz B is working even if has error on telnet...

Comment: *i got error when try telnet both servers on port 1433, that's weird coz B is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure A's SQL service is listening on 1433? Also, are there any firewalls preventing A from connecting on its SQL port?

Comment: I run "netstat -a" on machine A, I didn't see 1433.

Comment: You should be able to use the network configuraion manager to verify or set the TCP used by your SQL service. the "Verifying the port configuration of an instance of SQL Server" section of this aricle can explain how: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823938

Comment: thanks, just figured out that there is really something wrong with my SQL listening to the port. I installed SQL 2000 sp4 and seems to solve all my connectivity problems.